Extremely authentic and crystal clear hadiths on k!lling dogs - how do we come to peace with it?
Sahih Muslim #2015
Maimuna reported that one morning Allah’s Messenger was silent with grief. Maimuna said: Allah’s Messenger, I find a change in your mood today. Allah’s Messenger said: Gabriel had promised me that he would meet me tonight, but he did not meet me. By Allah, he never broke his promises, and Allah’s Messenger spent the day in this sad mood. Then it occurred to him that there had been a puppy under their cot. He commanded and it was turned out. He then took some water in his hand and sprinkled it at that place. When it was evening Gabriel met him and he said to him: You promised me that you would meet me the previous night. He said: Yes, but we do not enter a house in which there is a dog or a picture. Then on that very morning he commanded the k!lling of the dogs until he announced that the dog kept for the orchards should also be k!lled, but he spared the dog meant for the protection of extensive fields or big gardens.
Sunan Abi Dawud #2845 (Sahih - Al Albaani)
Narrated Abdullah ibn Mughaffal:
The Prophet (ﷺ) said: Were dogs not a species of creature I should command that they all be k!lled; but k!ll every pure black one.
Sahih al-Bukhari #3323
Narrated Abdullah bin `Umar:
Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) ordered that the dogs should be k!lled.
I have no idea how this is justifiable. From whatever justifications I've seen, they say its

The "dogs" are not dogs but hyenas, wolf, etc, if thats really the case then the scholars wouldn't cite these hadiths to say why we shouldn't pet dogs, or in the worst case to prove that its Sunnah to k!ll black dogs (even if they are not evil).
The dogs were disease causing and violent hence the Prophet allowed the k!llings - however they donot cite any authentic references for this, its just an assumption.

So from whatever material available, im getting the picture from the first hadith that the he ordered the k!llings of dogs just because a puppy under his bed prevented Angel Gabriels from entering his house.
If there is any better explaination to these hadiths please mention it below.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongly recommend you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. Any hadith no matter what its authenticity level might be cannot easily over rule the qur'an which mentioned dogs as pets, as hounds etc.. so in best case these ahadith cover specific rulings/cases that scholars have explained.

@Medi1Saif Salam! I agree with you that Hadith literature cannot overule the Qur'an. At the same time even though the command may or maynot be abrogated, how do you justify the fact that Prophet Muhammad gave a blanket order to k!ll dogs? and the reason for it a puppy being under his bed?

The Prophet ﷺ did originally command to kill all dogs in general:

كان رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم يأمر بقتل الكلاب فننبعث في المدينة وأطرافها فلا ندع كلبا إلا قتلناه حتى إنا لنقتل كلب المرية من أهل البادية يتبعها
The Messenger of Allah used to order that dogs be killed, and I went throughout Al-Madinah,
and we did not spare any dog but we killed it, to such an extent that we would even kill the dog
of a woman belonging to the desert people.
— Muslim

However later he forbade it. The command to kill them is abrogated and there is disagreement among the jurists on whether that means that killing them now is  haram, makruh tanzihi or merely permissible. The evidence of the abrogation includes:

أمرنا رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم بقتل الكلاب حتى إن المرأة تقدم من البادية بكلبها فنقتله ثم نهى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم عن قتلها وقال عليكم بالأسود البهيم ذي النقطتين فإنه شيطان
The Messenger of Allah ﷺ ordered us to kill dogs, and even if a woman came
from the desert with her dog, we would kill it. Then the Prophet forbade killing them, and said: You should kill the dark black (dog) with two (white) spots (above its eyes), for it is a devil.
— Muslim


أمر رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم بقتل الكلاب ثم قال ما بالهم وبال الكلاب ثم رخص في كلب الصيد وكلب الغنم
The Messenger of Allah enjoined the killing of dogs, then he said: 'What is the problem with them (people) and dogs?' Then he granted a concession with regard to dogs for hunting and herding sheep.
— Muslim


لولا أن الكلاب أمة من الأمم لأمرت بقتلها
Were it not that dogs form one of the communities (or nations - of creatures), I would have commanded that they be killed.
— Nasai {because it states that killing them is not commanded because of the reason given}


لا تتخذوا شيئا فيه الروح غرضا
Do not make anything having life as a target.
— Muslim {based on the argument that dogs are included in those that have life}

The above is regarding a dog which is known to be harmless to the people, if it is harmful then it is permitted and it can even be obligatory to kill it. This is because the sanctity of humans and their property is greater than that of an animal and because it is also evident from the hadith:

خمس فواسق يقتلن في الحل والحرم الحية والغراب الأبقع والفارة والكلب العقور والحديا
There are five vermin which may be killed inside the sanctuary and outside: Snakes, crows, mice, vicious dogs and kites.
— Muslim

Note that when the killing of dogs is permissible then that means one which is wild. If it is one tamed for a halal purpose such as for hunting or guarding then it can not be killed as it is destruction of another person's lawful property.
The wisdom behind culling dogs could be to prevent the harms they cause, such as:

their presence at a place is repulsive to angels
they make things ritually unclean as they are either unclean themselves or their saliva is unclean
their presence facilitates people in keeping them as pets which is a sinful practice
they bark at, frighten and chase people and make them unwelcome
they may bite causing injury,  and may even kill
they are a vector for spreading diseases

General extermination is a feasible way to reduce these harms. You may know that various governments carry out exterminations when they feel that it is necessary for example the culling of emus, camels, rabbits, rodents, mosquitoes and dogs.
The Prophet ﷺ commanded killing dogs when he thought it served some benefit. Later he withdrew this command so that some dogs would remain to serve useful purposes such as hunting or guarding or for their natural benefits such as control of other pests.
To come to peace with it you should work on strengthening your Iman. A true Muslim trusts the Prophet's ﷺ wisdom and accepts that whatever the Prophet ﷺ did was correct. Further a Muslim holds the Prophet ﷺ in higher regard than his own life and the lives of his parents and children, let alone the life of a dog. The criterion of good and bad for a Muslim is what the Prophet ﷺ taught and not his own whims and sympathies.

فلا وربك لا يؤمنون حتى يحكموك فيما شجر بينهم ثم لا يجدوا في أنفسهم حرجا مما قضيت ويسلموا تسليما
But no, by your Lord, they will not [truly] believe until they make you, [O Muhammad], judge concerning that over which they dispute among themselves and then find within themselves no discomfort from what you have judged and submit in [full, willing] submission.
— Quran 4:65


وما كان لمؤمن ولا مؤمنة إذا قضى الله ورسوله أمرا أن يكون لهم الخيرة من أمرهم ومن يعص الله ورسوله فقد ضل ضلالا مبينا
It is not for a believing man or a believing woman, when Allah and His Messenger have decided a matter, that they should [thereafter] have any choice about their affair. And whoever disobeys Allah and His Messenger has certainly strayed into clear error.
— Quran 33:36


"The Prophet ﷺ commanded killing dogs when he thought it served the Muslims' interests" how did you come to this conclusion? it appears as if the main reason he wanted to kill dogs only because a puppy didn't let Angel Jibreel a.s enter. reasons that you mentioned have 0 backing except for Najas reasons.

The apparent reason as per the hadith is that angels do not enter a place where there is a dog, this is a harm as angels bring mercy and blessings to people. In one hadith about killing a كلب العقور the mention of being vicious and being listed alongside other animals which harm people indicates that harm is a reason. Another hadith states that a particular black dog is to be killed because it is 'a devil' which is explained by some scholars to mean that it has greater malice and is more harmful and aggressive, this again indicates that such harm is reason.

but in the hadith above he commands to kill every dog, without differentiating between Rabid or Normal, secondly all the research and studies say there is no relation between aggressive behavior and coat color, and this is a myth that black dogs are more aggressive, i could cite them if you want. @UmH
